# Simulate interleaving execution python unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

It's my first time doing unit testing and I have to test an object that uses an internal token to generate an access token from a server.

I have to work with the following constraints:

1. Every internal token can generate an access token at a time.
2. Every time an internal token generates a new access token it invalidates any previous token generated.
3. After some minutes the access token becomes invalidated.
4. The object that uses the access token is shared between threads.

Incoming requests try to use the object which needs the access token to execute some methods.
Since I have no way of knowing if I have a valid access token unless I ask directly to the server I made a decorator that encapsulates every method that uses this access token.
Constraint 4 forced me to insert a semaphore, because of 2 I cannot allow that two requests try to use the token, one invalidating the other and viceversa.

What the decorator does is lock the object internal semaphore, try to use the current access token if any, and requires a new access token, trying to accomplish the request, releasing the semaphore.
I'd like to interleave the execution of the decorator so I can manually 'inject' disturbance

Is this possible using unittest?
Can I somehow force the GIL to behave in the way I intend to?

Basic testing seems to be successful but I would like to test it more thoroughly.

Comment: This is simultaneously too abstract _and_ too specific. It is too abstract because you provide only prose explaining your constraints instead of showing actual code that _does_ something and that you want to test. And it is too specific because all that "token" and "server" talk seems to be _irrelevant_ to the actual underlying issue you are asking about. I would suggest you try to come up with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the core functionality (threads, semaphore and one shared object) relevant to your question.